# SQL Query to find Department whose average salary is greater than 500000 in Single table

Tags: mysql, sql

This is table employee with following columns and data and I want to find out the designation whose average salary is greater than 500000.

```
idnew_table, Designation, Name, Salary
'1', 'ABC', 'anubhav', '500001'
'2', 'ABC', 'utsav', '2'
'3', 'HHHH', 'ddd', '1000000'
'4', 'TT', 'dss', '2'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. 
We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. 
Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. 
See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page for details.

Comment: Why `salary` values are strings, not numeric? What if `salary` in some row is NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` as follows:

```
select designation
  from employees 
 group by designation
 having avg(salary) > 500000
```

Comment: This is very frustrating. Without comment, DV will not help improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the type of salary column to `INT` with `CAST(expression AS [data type])` in order to have an `AVG` result. Also with `HAVING` in sql you can add a condition.

```
SELECT designation
FROM employees
GROUP BY designation 
HAVING avg(cast(salary as int)) >500000
```